# How long it takes to render in Freestyle mode?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, freestyle, memory-management

I am a beginner in Blender, and I have a question for you if you can help me.

I have a scene with multiple objects and a total of **1,731,619 triangles** and I am rendering in **Eevee in Freestyle**.

I have two computers, one is a Mac M1 and the other one is a Windows with a CPU AMD Ryzen 5 3500X, 6x 3.60 GHz, GPU NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660 Super 6GB and RAM 16GB.

I am testing both computers to **render a frame with a resolution 1920 x 1080 px** and the result is:

**MAC M1: 39 sec** [image]

**WINDOWS: 1 min and 03 sec** [image]

It seems that both computers uses normally the CPU and GPU, but the memory is used to the maximum.

My question is:

- Is it normal, for computers with good qualities, to take so long to render in freestyle?
- Am I doing something wrong?
- Is the scene too heavy?
- Or do I just need more memory? Do you think that if I buy 32 GB of RAM it would make a difference? Or should I just get a better computer?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: On my behalf I can say my hardware is mostly like your Windows PC and yes, it is a heavy scene. From my personal experience I can tell that getting more RAM will help but it's not creating magic ;) Surely a better computer will improve things, the question how much you want to spend and how much better it will get... that's hard to tell beforehand, surely we cannot tell in precise numbers like render time in seconds for example. What helped me with heavy smoke simulations that crashed was rendering from the command line. Not only they didn't crash after a while, they also rendered much faster.

Comment: Thank you Gordon!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use Grease Pencil instead of Freestyle, there you get also more freedom to define whre you want to have intersections and where not. Grease Oencil can interprete also already set Freestyle edges.

Basically calculating outlines or lines in 3D can be very time consuming.

Comment: Thank you Christoph. I ll try it!